# When should CSRF tokens be needed?

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

When deleting the list item, is it necessary to confirm that it is a correct request by using CSRF token ?

I think the csrf token necessity depends on the importance of the data to be deleted. I wonder my idea is correct?

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1 <button type="button" onclick="deleteItem()">delete</button></li>
    <li>item 2 <button type="button" onclick="deleteItem()">delete</button></li>
    <li>item 3 <button type="button" onclick="deleteItem()">delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need csrf tokens when posting data.
Typically a client side secret"token" in  a form tag    or when doing an ajax call to the back end.

Answer (score 1):

By default yoy should use CSRF validation every time you modify data. In reality this use ro be when you do `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` request. In every case except from a `GET` request.

If  you accept requests without a CSRF-token, it's possible for another website to make requests on behalf of the user, malicious intent or not.